# What's the fastest way to make money online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Everything in the online world is expensive, well the best things are. We all want the luxurious apartment with 10 cars garage and the best weapons but to achieve that, we need money. Which missions or activities give the most cash ?

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE:** since the latest 1.0.3 patch, the quick replay has been removed. So sadly, from now on only the first completion gives 9000$, and every repeated run only 3000$.

"Violent Duct" from Gerald. It gives 9000$ and can be done solo in around 3-4 minutes. You have to be level 15 to start this mission. It is currently only the second best mission (as far as I know) to make money, but it's available from pretty early on and you can do it solo.

A few hints:

- do the mission on easy difficulty, you take less damage and still get
  the same reward
- a gun with high range comes in quite handy, get an AK-47 as soon as
  you have access to it
- flank them from the left side. As soon as you collect the coke, avoid
  the incoming enemies and just drive off the same way you came from

This mission was nerfed so it only gives you 3000$ per run after voting for repeat, but you can avoid that by pressing the R2 (quick restart) on PS3 (not sure about xbox, i guess right trigger) after rating the mission. The only problem with that is that you can't buy ammo between your runs. So bring a lot of ammo with you. If you run out of ammo, end the mission, restock and call Gerald until he gives you the same mission again.

Answer (score 7):

So far the fastest, funnest, and most consistent way I've found to make money is repeated replays of either races or survival.  Either way has distinct advantages and disadvantages.

- Races, especially point-to-point street races with supers, take about
  2-3 minutes and can net the winner 6K, plus some nice RP to boot. 
  The top 7-8 positions will also make some money, but not as much.  It
  pumps your driving skill to at the same time.  The difficulty here is
  that it takes some driving skill to win the races.
- Survival can also return some nice cash rewards.  Cash and RP are based on the level reached, though it's not hard to make it to level 4 and get 4K out of it.  This game type takes a bit longer, but has some other nice benefits.  First, you're going to pump your shooting skill pretty heavily.  Secondly, you'll get tons of ammo and weapon pickups.  If you pick up a weapon you'll get to keep it until you log out of the session. It's nice to have a free spare RPG in your back pocket for a few hours.

The key to both of these approaches is to get a solid group of cohorts to grind the replays with.  If you cut out having to wait for new player to join and people who like to loaf in the lobby, you can get very quick turn around.

Also don't forget to sell a car to LS Customs every 48 minutes.  The best cars can get you up to 8K.

Comment: I don't think you get to keep the weapons, I think they stay until you change sessions or log off.  That was my experience with the uzi anyway.

Comment: @turbo double checked this and you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, alright. This post is pretty outdated, more based on the first release of GTA Online. I saw recently a post was closed because it was a duplicate of this post, that's kinda unfourtunate because this was posted 6 years ago and can't serve much help for late-game grinding in my opinion, so I came here to put my answer in.

---

**EARLY GAME** (Job Grinding)

---

So, you just got off the plane, 12 in the chamber, 36 in the pocket. Firstly, I'd strongly reccomend to *not* try and kill that level 351 going around in their Zentorno, because each time you die, you gotta pay $500 in healthcare and bail bills. Also, deposit your money on the Maze Bank website on your phone, or else you'll drop yet another $500 each time you die.

What you should do however, is job grinding. A lot of jobs do in fact work, I personally grinded the Dispatch Missions given by Martin Madrazo (Mz on the map), however, these jobs require a second person, some four people. A tip here is to always play on Hard Mode. This gives you more money and I didn't find it to be that more dificult than Normal.

To summarize;

- Try and not drop money.
- Don't go after high-leveled players.
- Grind Jobs. (Easier with friends)

Gather some new weapons, experience, and abilities to buy more armor to move on to the;

---

**MID GAME** (Heisting)

---

This is where your profits can skyrocket if you do it right, you got two options here;

1. Buy your own luxury apartment (200k) and start your own heists.
2. Join another player's heists.

The latter being cheaper than setting heists up yourself, but an apartment can be bought after doing about 10 jobs nowadays, which has actually been brought upwards since the game was released, however, to my knowledge, the apartment heists haven't changed payout to match the inflating GTA prices, so sometimes this will be worse than job grinding.

If however, you get the "Casino Heist - Big Con" invite on your phone, try and get in.

Big Con is the easiest approach to the casino heist. Make sure that the player hosting has "Gruppe Sechs" as Entry Disguise, "Staff Lobby" as exit and "High Level" as buyer, if the host only gives you 15% of the cut, that's actually fine, some may give 20% or ask you how much money you have and change your cut accordingly, but don't over-negotiate. After this you could net yourself an easy 200k, just follow the other players in the lobby and listen.

A bonus option is to find someone kind enough to bring you along and help you, I personally have given a lvl 30 about 1 million by doing the casino heist with him over and over. If you get lucky like that you can get some very easy cash. Crews also help, try and find either a Grinder Crew or a "We will always help if you help back" kind of crew, don't however join the reccomended rockstar crews (the ones with a pointy end to their tags), these crews are notoriousley toxic across the community, and of course there's the good, but the IGN crew especially is known to be the most toxic, cargo-greifing players to possess.

If you ever see an event going on, such as "Triple Rewards on Deadline!", Do, That, Job. My first week of playing I grinded the living life outta "Sumo: Remix" because it was double money and got myself probs 1 million by doing that.

To summarize;

- Do heists, preferably the more modern ones.
- Be friendly and eventually others will help back.
- Sieze any oppurtunity you find.
- Avoid the extremley large crews, find a small, loyal community.

When you have collected, maybe a few million, you'll be at the start of the;

---

**END GAME** (Bunkers, Coke, Cars, oh my!)

---

Personal taste is a strong part here, but I'll try my best to explain each business in detail shortly, you'll have to go down one of two paths;

*CEO*: Great for solo, decent for groups.
*MC*: Great for groups, terrible for solo.

The CEO is able to operate the following businesses:

- Bunker
- Import/Export
- Special Cargo
- Nightclub
- Hangar

also can operate these non-businesses;

- Office (Everything is done through the computer in there, apart from that, nothing)
- Arcade (Only 5k/day max, alright?)
- Facility (Don't bring up the orbital cannon.)

They can also register as VIP without having 50k in the bank, making VIP work such as Headhunter or Sightseer easy to get at. These missions can net you 20-25k in the span of 5 mins using a Buzzard (which are on sale atm go get one).

Your best solo buildings are as follows:

- Bunker (1 Vehicle Sales from 1 Supply Purchase)
- Import/Export (1 Source, 1 Sell = 80k)
- Nightclub (Only 1 Vehicle Sales)

You unlock CEO by buying an Office from the same website you buy houses from. A CEO's organization can have the CEO and 3 Associates/Bodyguards (Depending on how the player is invited) alongside. You also have access to VIP Abilites as CEO such as;

- Dropping BST (2x Damage + 1/2 Damage Taken for 1 Minute)
- Spawning Vehicles that you own right next to you (Select vehicles, such as Buzzard)
- Bribe Authorities (No wanted level for 2 mins)
- Ghost Organization (3 min off-radar for all members AND for driven sell vehicles)

The MC branch of businesses are better with friends, losing acces to both the Special Cargo and Import/Export for 5 businesses that work similarly to the bunker.

The MC President is able to operate the following businesses;

- Bunker
- Hangar
- MC Businesses
- Nightclub

and can also operate these non-business buildings;

- Arcade
- Clubhouse (Only MC contracts)
- Facility

Your best team-businesses are as follows;

- MC Businesses (1 Supply gets multiple vehicles)
- Hangar (Get 4 crates with 4 players)

You can also spawn any motorcycle stored in your Clubhouse through the MC menu. A MC can hold 8 Members in total, and the President can promote members for more abilities.

You can become a MC President after buying a Clubhouse from Maze Bank Foreclosures.

For both branches, the Arcade can be useful for the MCT. It costs a fair bit (on sale atm) but allows you to buy supplies for all businesses from the comfort of it.

Of course, anything other than the Clubhouse, Office, MC Businesses, Special Cargo and Import/Export can be done by both MC and CEO effectivley, CEO can have 4 players, and MC can have 1.

To summarize;

- Buy Businesses from Online
- CEO better solo
- MC Better with friends

---

**GREIFERS**

---

A grinder's worst enemy, a player that serves to ruin sell missions and kill level 7 Timmy who's bringing a car to LS Customs on a broomstick. You may have experienced them early on, but be ready now. Since you are playing in Freemode now instead of a private job, others can join and destroy your cargo. I'm a culprit of this myself, level 30 I saw a red truck nearby and blew it up with grenades, GRENADES, not knowing that in reality I just destroyed probs 120k of cocaine.

You can avoid greifers through this;

1. Be Attentive
2. Be Quick
3. Be Private

Being Attentive of any Off-Radars or Facility Jumps can help massivley, if you think a player is coming after you off-radar, use Ghost Organization yourself, they can't track your vehicle like that.

If you think an orbital cannon is after you, use off-radar, they can't lock on during that time.

Know all the icons for the special vehicles, if no special icon is appearing on the player, and they have the default player blip, still be careful. They can use a nightshark with 5 stickies strapped to it to deal basically no damage to themselves and instantly destroy a sell vehicle. Know counters of all vehicles.

Selling quickly can get the cargo safe before the local MK2 greifer even knows you are selling, avoid crashing and optimise routes, know what mission you are doing.

Create a Solo-Public lobby by cutting GTA's internet access temporarily with Resource Monitor. This'll prevent players from indirectly joining you for a couple of mins.

If all else fails, **GET OUT OF THE VEHICLE** and kill the greifer. If you are not inside, they can't lock onto you. (Unless they're using a terrorbyte, in that case, pretty unfourtunate)

---

So, that was it for my money guide, apologies if its a bit long but it needed to go here with the outdatedness, I'd love for some more people to comment and/or edit this post to keep it updated. Thanks for reading!